# Adding condition having index column in sql query does improve query performance?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am having question while updating record with this query having [`Identity column`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933196%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) in condition,

```
update TableName Set ColumnName = 'value' where ID = value
```

and my question is adding [`Index column`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492153.aspx) in where codition does improve query performace?
like this:

```
update TableName Set ColumnName = 'value' where ID = value and IndexColumn = 'indexColumnValue'
```

Comment: Well, your identity column is a primary key, right? In that case, the "index" is already there, so there's no gain from adding another one.

Comment: Do ass: given that ID runs down to already selecting ONE ROW - there is no chance the index column is going to be any more selective anyaway.

Answer (score 1):

That will only give improved performance under unusual circumstances

As Luaan points out the identity column will probably be a primary key and will certainly be unique so it's sufficient to identify the row on it's own.

However in the special case where the index on the Identity Column isn't Clustered and the index on the [IndexColumn] is then there should be a small performance gain (don't expect anything dramatic though).

If the identity index is unclustered and there's an index like

```
 CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX Clustered_i ON TableName (IndexColumn ,ID)
```

Or there's a filtered index along the lines of

```
CREATE INDEX Filtered_i ON TableName (ID) WHERE IndexColumn = 'indexColumnValue'
```

Then you might notice a small improvement as well but under normal circumstances just using the index on a Identity column will be about as fast as you can get.

The real difference though isn't in performance. Those queries are functionally different
if there's a record where

```
ID = value and IndexColumn <> 'indexColumnValue'
```

It will be updated by the first but not by the second.

Performance is important but actually performing the correct function is more important.